# Search in a rotated array

Tags: c++, search

```
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n=nums.size();
        int i=0, low, high;
        int pos=-1;
        while(nums[i]<nums[i+1])
            i++;
        //i stores the index of max element of the array
        if(target<nums[0]) {
            low = i+1;
            high = n-1;
        }
        else {
            low = 0;
            high = i;
        }
        while(low<=high) {
            int mid = (low+high)/2;
            // cout<<low<<high<<mid<<target;
            // cout<<(nums[mid]==target);
            if(nums[mid] == target){
                pos = mid;
                // flag=1;
                break;
            }
            else if(nums[mid]<target) {
                low = mid+1;
            }
            else {
                high = mid-1;
            }
        }
        // if (flag==0)
        //     return -1;
        return pos;
    }
};
```

**I have attached the code above**

```
    =================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000194 at pc 0x000000345587 bp 0x7fff5346e5a0 sp 0x7fff5346e598
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000194 thread T0
    #2 0x7f210b53a0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000194 is located 0 bytes to the right of 4-byte region [0x602000000190,0x602000000194)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7f210b53a0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
=>0x0c047fff8030: fa fa[04]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

This is the error message that I am getting on LeetCode. Could somebody look into this.
The question was to search is a rotated array that was initially sorted in an ascending order.
When I run this code, it works perfectly fine but when I try to submit, it gives the heap error.

Comment: Have you tested locally while building with address santizer enabled?

Comment: Definitely do the above. On your own computer you'll almost always get better diagnostics than the judge will give. Tricky part is prying the input set out of the judge if the error is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: `while(nums[i]<nums[i+1]) i++;` is unbounded. What happens when `i` increases past the end of the container? You may as well check to see if you find the target during that linear search. Consider using `at(index)` instead of `[index]` so an exception is thrown when you access out of bounds.

Comment: Or in this case `i+1` exceeds the container?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have put while(nums[i]<nums[i+1] && i<n) instead of that but still I am getting the same error

Comment: @StephenNewell I am running the code on leetcode. On clicking on run, the test cases pass but on clicking submit it gives error

Comment: @YashiGoyal *Could somebody look into this* -- Advice -- Programming is much more than writing a program and seeing it doesn't work.  You need to debug your code, and especially code that you wrote yourself.  Debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  The person who should be "looking into this" is -- yourself.  Otherwise you are asking one of us to do the job you're supposed to be doing.  We're not asking you to fix the problem, but at the very least, identify where the problem is, and you do that by debugging the code.

Comment: Try `while(i < (n - 1) && nums[i] < nums[i + 1])` so you check if you're going to go out of bounds before you actually do it. Without that the simple test case of one number in the vector fails with the same error you showed. https://godbolt.org/z/KK6Ke7TGM